# Binding a Kendo Observable to my view is not working

Tags: mvvm, kendo-ui

We are using Durandal JS in an ASP.NET MVC 4 project:

I am simply trying to bind some observables to my Html View as follows :

```
 <div id="nodetype" class="k-block ">
     <div class="pull-left" >
         <h3>Enter HVaR Parameters</h3>
          <ul>
            <li>
             <label>Liquidataion Days):  </label>
             <input id="liquidDays" data-bind="value: LiquidDays" class="k-textbox" />
            </li>
          </ul>
      </div>                    
  </div>
```

However "LiquidDays" observable remains at a value of "0".
I am expecting that my ViewModel code below would update "LiquidDays" and therefore bind it to my html text field:

ViewModel code :

```
 var vm = kendo.observable({
    activate: activate,
    onclickUpdate: UpdateMyStuff,
    title: title,
    LiquidDays: 0,
    ConfLevelPct: 99,
    periodType: "",
    attached: function (view) {
        loadHVarConfig();     
        kendo.bind($("#nodetype"), vm);           
    },
});
return vm;
```

and here's my binding function with Ajax call to server side :

```
 function loadHVarConfig() {        

    // LOAD CONFIG PARAMETERS !!
    var jq = $.ajax({
        url: '/api/breeze/GetVaRConfig',
        type: "get",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: 'application/json',            
    });
    jq.success(function (data) {
        bindHvarParams(data);              // ON SUCCESS BIND TO VIEW MODEL
    });

    }

    function bindHvarParams(data) {        

      // Set ViewModel properties from data array
      vm.set("LiquidDays", data[0].liquidationDays);        
      vm.LiquidDays = data[0].liquidationDays;
      vm.ConfLevelPct = data[0].confidenceLevel;
      vm.numOfObserv = data[0].historicPeriodLength_size;   
      vm.periodType = data[0].historicPeriodLength_unit;
      vm.holidayCal = data[0].calendarId;
      vm.startDateFixedPeriod = data[0].historicPeriodStart;

    }
```

I'm using this link as a guide but I'm missing something : http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/framework/mvvm/observableobject

thank you.
Bob

Comment: For now I ended up using basic jQuery binding.. i.e. $("#liquidDays").val(vm.LiquidDays); but I'm thinking the Kendo or even Knockout observables would serve me best and be more efficient.

Comment: Are you using Durandal?

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry for not clarifying. I just updated the post to confirm we are indeed using Durandal. And it's quite confusing why the only way I can bind to the UI components is by using standard jQuery binding (i.e. $("#myTextBox").text("Something goes here"); ). I should be able to bind via the view Model.

Answer (score 1):

kendo mvvm logic only works after executing kendo.bind() method.
You used kendo.bind() within observable attached function, But you dint call attached method.

```
For more details refer this
```

[working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cmLh3/)

Comment: Hello and thank you. I've updated my post to show what we've changed. I think there might be an issue with ajax call and success event, thereby not binding my view properly. Please see the updated code where I call function loadHVarConfig() in the "attached" event, which in turn makes an Ajax call. Then upon SUCCESS I call function bindHvarParams(data) and attempt to update the vm.

Comment: I see you're demo is working fine, however in our case we're going to the server to get the data via an Ajax call. We're populating the view model successfully, but it refuses to bind the the UI unless I use jquery - for example $("#bla").text(vm.myData);

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you followed the steps outlined here in order for Kendo and Durandal to play nice with each other: http://durandaljs.com/documentation/KendoUI/.

Second, if you followed the instructions above, in order for model-binding to work, you have to use the correct `data-` attributes on your HTML tags. For Durandal bindings, it's `data-bind=""` and for Kendo bindings it's `data-kendo-bind=""`.

Third, because of the above steps, you cannot mix Durandal (aka. Knockout) style binding with Kendo style binding. They are completely exclusive and incompatible with each other. This means that you cannot have any functions or properties that work only with Durandal inside a Kendo observable. To put it more plainly, you should not put `activate` or `attached` inside that Kendo observable. You should instead return the viewmodel like so:

```
return {
  activate: activate,
  attached: attached,
  viewModel: kendo.obeservable({
    onclickUpdate: UpdateMyStuff,
    title: title,
    LiquidDays: 0,
    ConfLevelPct: 99,
    periodType: ""
  })
};
```